# Negate bits not working as expected PHP

Tags: php, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

Here is my problem:

```
<?php
$a = ~5; //0101 => 1010
echo $a;//-6
```

As Negate operator converts ones to zeros and zeroes to ones,the output should have atleast been 10. Why I got -6 as output?

Comment: I'm not sure why you expect `~101b` to become `1010b` and then are surprised that you're actually getting `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111010b`...

Answer (score 1):

Because php uses 2-complement and treats your new `$a` as a signed integer.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement